# Is there an explanation for getting different counts on the same dataset when I use elastic search versus using AWS athena

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-athena

I am getting different counts when I use Athena SQL query versus Elastic Serach with a delta of 6% -8% lower for athena counts when  on the same logic to query a database. What is the explanation behind difference in counts using these two methods.

Comment: There is no way we can know, but essentially these are 2 very different services. elasticsearch (usually) involves preprocessing and tokenising the data which could lead to different results for "similar" queries. also maybe the underlying data is not the same?

Comment: The underlying data is exactly the same

Comment: This article  might explain some of the reasons
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html